# Core 0 and 2 of my cpu get more heated than other cores

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature

I have recently changed the thermal paste, but after that, I noticed that core 0 and 2 are almost about 95 when doing some heavy work. Is there anything I did wrong while implementing the new thermal paste? Or what should I do for these cores to have a lower temperature? You can see that max of other cores hardly touch 90
[image]

Comment: You need to spread an even, thin, layer of paste over the entire surface. That is likely what happened.

Comment: i changed the thermal paste, but the issue does not resolved. i tried my best to keep layer thin

Comment: I am not sure, except to suggest the CPU might have been damaged if the first application of thermal paste was not correct.

Comment: i did not find any issue in previous thermal paste. but before that, my laptop get really heatup and I cant even touch it keyboard. all cores are above 90. but now its normal, except these two core issues

Comment: You also need to make sure (you likely did) that the fan and airway are free of dust and dirt.

Comment: yes, it is. so what should i do next to take care of my laptop

Comment: I cannot offer any more than I have offered here.